# Setting value datetime-local on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I want to add value in my edit form, with the value take from my database. but I don't know how to add value in the form of type datetime-local. I've tried but not appear.

here my view :

```
<div class='form-group col-sm-6'>
                        <label>Date Start</label>
                        <input class='form-control' value='{{ @$row->date_start }}' readonly />
                        <input type='datetime-local' class='form-control' name='date_start' value='{{ @$row->date_start }}' required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group col-sm-6'>
                        <label>Date End</label>
                        <input  class='form-control' value='{{ @$row->date_end }}' readonly />
                        <input type='datetime-local' class='form-control' name='date_end' value='{{ @$row->date_end }}' required/>
                    </div>
```

and here my controller :

```
public function postEditSave($id) {
        $simpan= array();
        $simpan['date_start']=Request::input('date_start');
        $simpan['date_end']=Request::input('date_end');
        $simpan['condition_status']=Request::input('condition_status');
        $simpan['id_cms_users']=Request::input('id_cms_users');
        $simpan['id_cms_companies']=Request::input('id_cms_companies');

        DB::table('log_patrols')->where('id', $id)->update($simpan);
        Session::flash('edit', 'Berhasil merubah data');
        return redirect('patrols');
    }
```

and this my database :

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxgSw.png)

and for notice my **date_start** and **date_end** column is type **datespam**

can someone give me solution ? or did any other form input type can i use for my project ? which could take a date and time data directly? for to change type **datetime-local** ?

thanks...

*sorry for my bad english.*

Comment: The future is now... Carbon now has the "toDateTimeLocalString" format just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id="time" name="time" type="datetime-local" value="{{ now()->setTimezone('T')->format('Y-m-dTh:m') }}" form-control>
```

Just add this in the blade

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 26):

Add below accessors to your model. I think `Y-m-d\TH:i` is the only date format that `datetime-local` input accepts.

```
public function getDateStartAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
}

public function getDateEndAttribute($value)
{
    return Carbon::parse($value)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
}
```

And in your form

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date_start" value="{{$yourPassedVariable->date_start}}">

<input type="datetime-local" name="date_end" value="{{$yourPassedVariableToView->date_end}}">
```

And if you want to display your date fields in another format than `Y-m-d\TH:i` just add another accessor to your model and use it in your views.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to do it in your form you can do this

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date_start" value="{{ date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($yourPassedVariableToView)) }}">

<input type="datetime-local" name="date_end" value="{{ date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($yourPassedVariableToView)) }}">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<input id="time" name="time" type="datetime-local" value="{{old('time')?? date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($learning->time)) }}" class=" form-control @error('time') is-invalid @enderror" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

it \ you can use on model very easy implement on your model.

```
protected $casts = [
        'inicio'  => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i'
        ,'entrega'  => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i'
   ];
```

return all data formated for use.